# JS. assign event property type to a variable

Tags: javascript, variables, events

Not sure how to formulate a question, need to assign something like a type of event to a variable and then use it. For instance:

```
mx = ('ontouchstart' in document.documentElement) ? event.changedTouches[0].pageX : event.pageX;
```

then:

```
function fn(e) {
  return mx - elem1.getBoundingClientRect().left;
}
```

that is `e` -event object goes to `mx` and returns the assigned earlier event type (so that `мх` is either `e.changedTouches[0].pageX` or `e.pageX`).

Is it possible to do that? (otherwise, have to check for the support of ontouchstart each px of mouse move...)

Comment: how about you define two methods and use the one that has the right thing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do not want to do the if check on every iteration, than just defined the function with the version you want.

```
var fn = (function () {
  if ('ontouchstart' in document.documentElement){
     return function(event){
         return event.changedTouches[0].pageX - elem1.getBoundingClientRect().left
     }
  } else {
     return function(event){
         return event.pageX - elem1.getBoundingClientRect().left
     }
  }
}());
```

Comment: on iPhone/Safari I am getting error: TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'event.changedTouches') --- here: return function(event){ return event.changedTouches[0].pageX

Comment: I tried to assign e to event before calling fn - change noghing... can you suggest waht is wrong here?

Comment: I am not a touch expert, but is it touches vs changedTouches for iphone?

Comment: Thanks, but seems like it is not... tried targetTouches - the same. Tried to create a global var ev and assign local e to it, while assigning ev to event inside fn - still same error...